# iPhone bluetooth paired devices after app is not running?

Tags: iphone, pairing, gksession

Like in android, we can pair devices and even after restarting the app or device, these devices are in paired list, so it is possible same as in iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no public API to do so. Even you've done it by using private API, I doubt Apple will let your App show up in App Store.